# How can I tell if a Django object given by a parent class's Queryset is actually an object with related data in a child class?

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-queryset, django-orm

**My Problem:** In the `save()`, `clean()`, and one-off methods of a Model class, references are made to a child model's parent. These references fail in the child-of-child model, as the parent's parent needs to be referenced instead. Checking for `[object].[child-class name as attribute]` fails, as ALL objects have this attribute, but attempting to access it on objects without a related object in the child class's tables causes an Exception.

Given the following models:

```py
...
from django_extensions.db.fields import UUIDField

class Event(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField()
    ...

class TicketedEvent(Event):
    ...

    def save():
        # Do work with the parent's data
        ... self.event.uuid ...
        # TicketedConcert objects use this save() as well
        # but need to refer to self.ticketedevent.event.uuid

class TicketedConcert(TicketedEvent):
    ...
```

When looking in the results for `TicketedEvent.objects.all()` I see all TicketedEvent and TicketedConcert objects, and looking in the results for `TicketedConcert.objects.all()` shows me only TicketedConcert objects.

My intention was to detect if a given object in `TicketedEvent.objects.all()` is actually a TicketedConcert object, without needing to surround all of my work in `try:/except:`.

I expected that only objects which actually *are* `TicketedConcert` objects would have the attribute (given by `.select_related()`) `.ticketedconcert` containing the related data from the `TicketedConcert` model. When trying to `.exclude()` based on the existence (as True/False) of the subclass's attribute, this gave me the following error:

```py
>>> TicketedEvent.objects.select_related().exclude(ticketedconcert=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 557, in exclude
    return self._filter_or_exclude(True, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 566, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1191, in add_q
    self.add_q(child, used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1072, in add_filter
    can_reuse)
  File "/Users/Bryson/.virtualenvs/spyon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1521, in split_exclude
    if active_positions[-1] > 1:
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Additionally, I attempted to `.exclude()` based on existance/Null as follows:

```py
>>> TicketedEvent.objects.select_related().exclude(ticketedconcert__isnull=True)
[<TicketedEvent: Event Name>, <TicketedEvent: Event Name>]
```

Both returned events are, in fact, a `TicketedConcert`. Checking for null on the existance of the subclass as an attribute has returned only objects that actually have a subclass object. Apparently, **every single object returned by the parent model has the subclass as an attribute, but accessing it on non-subclassed objects fails.** My expected result for this was that only objects that actually had as associated subclass object would have the attribute.

This is my problem. How can I actually tell if, when accessed by the parent class, an object actually has data in that attribute (thus is actually a child class)?

My original attempt was as follows:

```py
if hasattr(self, ticketedconcert):
    # do a different set of work on this data, it's a concert
else:
    # do normal, non-concert work upon this data
```

This continued to give me errors, because *every object has that attribute* regardless of its ability to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.objects.exclude(
    id__in=TicketedConcert.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
)
```

"My intention was to prevent the TicketedConcert subclass objects from being included in the parent class's results."

```
TicketedEvent.objects.exclude(
    id__in=TicketedConcert.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution to work with instances. eg:

```
if tevent.id in TicketedConcert.objects.values_list('id', flat=True):
    # the event is a concert
else:
    # the event is not a TicketedConcert
```

But, it will work and not be too horribly unperformant (maybe).

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything about the object, it just excludes concerts from the results.

Comment: I must misunderstand `My intention: to exclude objects of a model (a) that is a subclass of another model (b) from model b's admin interface.`

Comment: `My problem: I do not know how to filter these objects from the queryset`

Comment: Oops, that was left over from asking another question that shared a portion of this question. My mistake.